# Adding shapes to polygon feature in the same row

Tags: qgis, shapefile, polygon, area

I've got somehow simple issue but cannot process it.
I am working with shapefile in QGIS (3.10 on MacOS), where having several polygon features stored as rows. I want to somehow (manually) edit some of those features (pink one on the print screen) to add additional one (pink one the print screen) or two polygons nearby. To have them together in the same row, so just reshape polygon somehow as I need to process with area calculation and other analysis and need them to be in the same row.

Tried to google but maybe I am missing something obvious

[image: problem]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to combine the geometries, that makes them a multipart geometry with a single record in the attribute table.

To do this, follow this procedure:

1. Activate the layer edition
2. Select the entities
3. `Edit` menu > `combine selected space objects` or use the respective button on the toolbar

Comment: That solved it. Thanks, great.